# How to get corner of a square

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

Hi all I having troubles with physics in spriteKit so I decided to make my own, and I need to get the corners of a square. I've tried

```
    _hero.position.x-_hero.size.width/2-_hero.size.height/2
```

which I thought it was giving me the down left corner of a square, but when I run my game it doesn't do what I expect. I'm doing a 2D "super mario galaxy" which means that my player runs in circles in little planets, the thing is, I need to put the corners positions in an `if()` that will check, for example, that the top right corner of the player is greater than the bottom left corner of a square, and in that case I will set a `BOOL` that will tell the program the player is under the square, because `didBeginContact` is buggy, I had a lot of problems with it. Anyone's help would be great.

PD: I leave a sample of my game, it's still very primitive but hope you like the concept and optionally, any feedback (good or bad) is welcome.

[image]

Comment: you should only subtract width from x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square would have an origin and a frame. See below. It may be easier to [convert](http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Converting+Between+Coordinate+Spaces) from the local coordinate system (square) to the parent's coordinate system if you are trying to find each corner.

[image: And object's coordinates]

However, I think your actual question would be about collision detection. In that case, make a `CGRect` of each object and then see if they intersecting using `CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1,rect2)`

Answer (score 0):

twodayslate has some good information, but I thought I would add that there are some pretty cool CGRect APIs that I didn't know were available until recently. Consider this rect:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200);
```

Using the following methods will return some nice convenient results:

```
CGRectGetWidth(rect) --> 100
CGRectGetHeight(rect) --> 200
CGRectGetMaxX(rect) --> 200
CGRectGetMaxY(rect) --> 300
```

This is compared to what most people use:

```
rect.size.width
rect.size.height
rect.origin.x + rect.size.width
rect.origin.y + rect.size.height
rect.origin.x + rect.size.width
```